# Rails 3.0 devise account validation from admin to user - undefined method `edit_user_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to make an admin account to validate the registration of a user, for that I have 2 devise models: admin and user.

**I've followed these steps:**
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in

But from the view I get this error:
Undefined method `edit_user_path'

**This is my app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  def active_for_authentication? 
    super && approved? 
  end 

  def inactive_message 
    if !approved? 
      :not_approved 
    else 
      super # Use whatever other message 
    end 
  end

  def self.send_reset_password_instructions(attributes={})
    recoverable = find_or_initialize_with_errors(reset_password_keys, attributes, :not_found)
    if !recoverable.approved?
      recoverable.errors[:base] << I18n.t("devise.failure.not_approved")
    elsif recoverable.persisted?
      recoverable.send_reset_password_instructions
    end
    recoverable
  end
end
```

**App/controllers/unapproved_users_controller.rb**

```
class UnapprovedUsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:approved] == "false"
      @users = User.find_all_by_approved(false)
    else
      @users = User.all
    end
  end
end
```

**App/views/unapproved_users.html.haml**

```
%h1 Users

= link_to "All Users", :action => "index"
|
= link_to "Users awaiting approval", :action => "index", :approved => "false"

%table
    - @users.each do |user|
        %tr
            %td= user.email
            %td= user.approved
            %td= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(user)
```

**This path makes the problem:**
= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(user)

Comment: http://thekindofme.wordpress.com/2010/01/31/notes-on-setting-up-devise-authentication-solution-for-rails/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #1 - Check `rake routes` for the correct helper

Option #2 - You need to setup an administrator interface to edit users as I'm pretty sure devise only provides the interface for `current_user` not for people wanting to edit another user.

Option #3 - Use something like [RailsAdmin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin)

Comment: #1 In rake routes the closest path to edit_user is edit_user_registration, which asks me to sign in before continuing.
#2 Is in the administration app/views/unapproved_users.html.haml where I get the error.

Comment: What I'm saying for #2 is have an edit and update action in the UnapprovedUsersController, and then setup your normal everyday connector code for this, make a view, and bam you're ready to go (don't forget to add a route too of course). Assuming your route for the UnnaprovedUsersController is `resources :unapproved_users` or whatever, then you can change `edit_user_path` to `edit_unapproved_user_path`. :)

Comment: One more question please, I get an error when I update the boolean. In controller I have both def edit/update @user = User.find(params[:id]), in the view/form my form helper is = form_for (@user, :url => { :action => 'update'}) do |f|. The element is = f.check_box :approved

Comment: Check if you have added the attribute to the `attr_accessible` on the user model so you can mass assign it.

Comment: yep I have attr_accessible :approved... However you answered the main question giving a great explanation, so I've created a different question for this new case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423354/rails-devise-update-column-from-another-controller