# Rails Devise - Update column from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Rails 3.0
Following these instructions:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in
I've generated a migration :approved (boolean) for my devise user.rb. Now I want to edit it with a checkbox from a different controller: unapproved_users_controller.rb.
When I load the form in the edit I get this error: undefined method `user_path'.

**routes.rb**, the resources for my new controller

```
resources :unapproved_users
```

**app/models/user.rb**, notice that :approved is attr_accessible.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :approved

  def active_for_authentication? 
    super && approved? 
  end 

  def inactive_message 
    if !approved? 
      :not_approved 
    else 
      super # Use whatever other message 
    end 
  end

  def self.send_reset_password_instructions(attributes={})
    recoverable = find_or_initialize_with_errors(reset_password_keys, attributes, :not_found)
    if !recoverable.approved?
      recoverable.errors[:base] << I18n.t("devise.failure.not_approved")
    elsif recoverable.persisted?
      recoverable.send_reset_password_instructions
    end
    recoverable
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/unapproved_controllers.rb**

```
class UnapprovedUsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:approved] == "false"
      @users = User.find_all_by_approved(false)
    else
      @users = User.all
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  end  

end
```

**app/views/unapproved_users/index.html.haml**

```
%h1 Users

= link_to "All Users", :action => "index"
|
= link_to "Users awaiting approval", :action => "index", :approved => "false"

%table
    - @users.each do |user|
        %tr
            %td= user.email
            %td= user.approved
            %td= link_to "Edit", edit_unapproved_user_path(user)
```

**app/views/unapproved_users/edit.html.haml**

```
= render 'form'
```

**app/views/unapproved_users/_form.html.haml**

```
= form_for (@user) do |f|

  -if @user.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this user from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  .field
    = f.label :approved, 'Approved?'
    = f.check_box :approved 
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the form_for.

It should be

```
= form_for(@user, :url => unapproved_user_path(@user)) do |f|
```